# Multi monitor setup problem - 3 displays (2 monitors + 1 TV)

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

I have difficulties configuring a multimonitor setup in Ubuntu that contains 3 displays.

I have a PC with a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 550ti graphics card that has 3 outputs: 1 mini HDMI, 2 DVI. I run the NVIDIA display driver version 375.66 (if that helps somehow).

I now have two monitors that I want to use alongside. One monitor is the main, the other one is the extension of monitor one. That works well, but when I want to include my TV in this monitor setup I can either use

- TV and monitor 1 or
- monitor 1 + 2

but not all three devices.

My goal is to use

- monitor 1 + 2 alongside and
- mirror monitor 1 with my TV.

Is there any way this can be done?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any other display card other than NVIDIA?

Comment: Although many cards have more then two outputs the driver usually limits the usage to only two at the same time.

Comment: @Rengas The mainboard of my PC has another video output but other than that the NVIDIA card is the only one I have

Comment: The things I just tried are: connecting one monitor to my mainboard, changing bios settings to enable the motherboards graphics card and use the NVIDIA drivers. It works until I log in. The Unity greeter is displayed correctly on all three monitors, but when I log in the monitor 2 turns black and no windows can be moved there but the mouse is visible.

Comment: @NicNacDeluxe In my Pc i have both NVIDIA 2 outputs and 3 on the mother board. I had to remove NVIDIA card to get the 3 monitors working. Are you able to get the EDID info of third monitor? Also post your xrog.log when you connect 3 monitors?

Comment: @Rengas "Are you able to get the EDID info of third monitor? Also post your xrog.log when you connect 3 monitors?" could you please tell me how to do that? I will post both down below afterwards

Comment: This is what the setup looks now [current setup](https://i.imgur.com/nvGux0a.png). The third monitor is recognized but only the cursor can be moved there, no windows